# Getting "undefined" when passing params using react-navigation version 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

**TLDR**: I am not getting a param passed from one screen to the next using route.params in react-navigation 5.

I just updated from react-navigation version 4 to version 5. I am now having problems passing params between screens. in the screen I am navigating from I use an onPress() to navigate to the next screen and pass a string "son" in the parameter "loveOne".

from the first screen here are the important bits of code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
.
.
.
class RegistrationPageTwo extends React.Component {
.
.
.
    render(){
        const { radiochecked } = this.state;
        const { navigation } = this.props;
.
.
.
        onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('RegistrationThree', { params: { loveOne: "son" },})}}
.
.
.
// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return <RegistrationPageTwo {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

in the called screen "RegistrationPageThree" I do the following:

```
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
.
.
.
    render(){
        const { route } = this.props
        const { loveOne } = route.params;
        console.log("entering render section: " + loveOne );
.
.
.
// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
    const route = useRoute();

    return <RegistrationPageThree {...props} route={ route } />;
  } 

I am getting "undefined" for loveOne in the consolelog statement.

I have been over the react-navigation 5 documentation and can't seem to pull out what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for the help!

Garry O.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are passing params is used for nested navigators, In your case with a direct navigation you just have to change this line

```
onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('RegistrationThree', {  loveOne: "son" })}}
```

The reason you are getting undefined is that your variable is wrapped inside params

Comment: Thank you Guruparan! it fixed it. I have a nested navigation (stack + drawer) further down the screen stack and assumed that was the way to call no mater which navigation stack you are in.