# Error: React Native Navigation 5x - route.params undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

**I'm not getting params in route props on the screen I'm going to.**

I try to send data from one screen to another but it does not arrive in the props route.params

Here I leave the versions that appear in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
  }
```

In screen 1 I have this code

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';

export default function Screen1() {

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    function goToScreen2(data) {
        navigation.navigate('Screen2', { "data": data });
    }

    return (
        <View>{{'Code here'}}</View>
    )

}
```

And on the Screen2 I receive it as follows

```
export default function Screen2({ navigation, route }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(route.params))
        const data = route.params.data;
    }, []);
}
```

Please, I already searched and tried everything and nothing works.
Included this post [Getting "undefined" when passing params using react-navigation version 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917171/getting-undefined-when-passing-params-using-react-navigation-version-5)
But I can't get it to work, although I don't see it differently.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: I already found the problem. I'm using this **"@react-navigation/drawer"** library, the **createDrawerNavigator** method. I removed it and now it works, the thing is that I ran out of side menu, so now I'm looking at how to replace that library.

Comment: when you use drawer you have to use nested params with that. check the reference docs